# CSS hover on classList

Tags: javascript, css

I have elements with class **.tab** and hover for them:

```
.tab:hover {
    background-color: #A9E59E;
}
```

Now, I'm adding additional class to some of those element in JS:

```
this.classList.toggle('tab2');
```

the problem is, I do not wan't hover to fire on those elements with two classes
**classList.length > 1**.
Is there a way in CSS to exclude those elements with two classes, so that hover fires only on **.tab** class, and not on **.tab .tab2**
or I need to move all *hover logic* to JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use CSS3 the :not selector can help you achieve what you are after:

```
.tab:not(.tab2):hover {
    background-color: #A9E59E;
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to define a new rule for elements having both classes in order to reset the background-color:

```
.tab:hover {
    background-color: #A9E59E;
}
.tab.tab2:hover {
    background-color: white; (or whatever your initial background color was)
}
```

Comment: .tab:not(.tab2):hover is the first solution comes up in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the `:not` selector?

You can try something like this:

```
.tab:not(.tab2):hover {
    background-color: #A9E59E;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax.

```
    [class="tab"]:hover{
background-color: #A9E59E;
}
```

Which will select the class tab ,if it has other class attributes it wont get selected.

Comment: in the matter of speed, which selector is faster, this or **:not**?

Comment: I think its faster than :not because [] is default definition,where with :not we are explicitly specifiying the thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another explicit rule for the 2 classes

```
.tab.tab2:hover {
  background-color: #someothercolor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
.tab.tab2:hover{
/*apply the same style as for the non hover element */
}
```

Comment: This will not work since the existing rule for `.tab:hover` will still apply

Comment: You are right. Maybe better to rephrase what I mean with "do nothing here"

Answer (score 0):

We can remove hover effects using

```
$(element).removeClass('hover');
```

So while toggling classes we also can toggle hover

```
element.classList.toggle("tab2");
element.classList.toggle("hover");
```